# Cardinality of even and odd number of elements in Power Set

Tags: proof-writing, binomial-coefficients

I wish to prove that the number of sets in a power set is $2^n$ by using the fact that
$$\sum^{n+1}_{k=0} \binom{n}{k} a^kb^{n+1-k}.$$
After that, I wish to use that sum formula to prove that the cardinality of even and odd number of elements in a power set have the same quantity, so it is always $2^{n-1}$, but how can I use the sum formula to prove that?

Comment: How about using $a=b=1$?

Comment: the same way like with $2^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the binomial theorem with
(i) a=1, b=1
(ii) a=1, b=-1